# Color fading function

Tags: c, bitwise

I found this old color fading function in my snippets folder and would like to implement it to one of my projects. It can be used to fade one color to another. It's a very long one-liner:

```
D3DCOLOR GetFadedColor(D3DCOLOR from, D3DCOLOR to, float factor)
{
    return (factor<0.0f)?from:((factor>1.0f)?to:(((((from>>24)>(to>>24))?((from>>24)-
    (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((from>>24)-(to>>24)))):((from>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)
    ((to>>24)-(from>>24)))))<<24)|(((((from<<8)>>24)>((to<<8)>>24))?(((from<<8)>>24)-
    (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from<<8)>>24)-((to<<8)>>24)))):(((from<<8)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)
    (factor*(float)(((to<<8)>>24)-((from<<8)>>24)))))<<16)|(((((from<<16)>>24)>
    ((to<<16)>>24))?(((from<<16)>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from<<16)>>24)-
    ((to<<16)>>24)))):(((from<<16)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to<<16)>>24)-
    ((from<<16)>>24)))))<<8)|(((((from<<24)>>24)>((to<<24)>>24))?(((from<<24)>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)
    (factor*(float)(((from<<24)>>24)-((to<<24)>>24)))):(((from<<24)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*
    (float)(((to<<24)>>24)-((from<<24)>>24))))))));

}
```

`D3DCOLOR` is just a `DWORD` (`unsigned long`). A color can for example be 0xAARRGGBB (A-alpha, R-red, G-green, B-blue), but works with other compositions aswell.

Obviously it's a total mess.

I actually don't know how it works and don't remember where I have it from, so I would ask for a review to improve the code and make it readable and understandable.

Comment: Since we don't deal with code errors, you can post about them on Stack Overflow.  After getting them fixed, you could make those changes here and we'll help with the readability.

Comment: @JamalA Thanks, I managed to get the code working now. It's still kind of ugly.

Comment: No problem.  Someone may be able to help with that.

Comment: There were still some errors in the code. It is fully working now. I also made it better visible in the post.

Comment: Asking for a rewrite of someone else's code is off-topic for Code Review. Also, the code was posted without attribution.

Answer (score 6):

This is the reason why some people want ternary operators removed from the language. It's not quite the worst abuse I've seen, but it's pretty close. This took quite a while to disentangle. I'm going to go through it in steps:

First step: make it slightly more readable. Break up everything:

```
return (factor<0.0f)
?
from 
: 
((factor>1.0f)
?
to
:
(((((from >> 24) > (to >> 24))
?
((from>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((from>>24)-(to>>24))))
:
((from>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((to>>24)-(from>>24)))))<<24)
|
(((((from<<8)>>24)>((to<<8)>>24))
?
(((from<<8)>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from<<8)>>24)-((to<<8)>>24))))
:
(((from<<8)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to<<8)>>24)-((from<<8)>>24)))))<<16)
|
(((((from<<16)>>24)>((to<<16)>>24))
?
(((from<<16)>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from<<16)>>24)-((to<<16)>>24))))
:
(((from<<16)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to<<16)>>24)-((from<<16)>>24)))))<<8)
|
(((((from<<24)>>24)>((to<<24)>>24))
?
(((from<<24)>>24)-(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from<<24)>>24)-((to<<24)>>24))))
:
(((from<<24)>>24)+(D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to<<24)>>24)-((from<<24)>>24))))))));
```

Not a hell of a lot of improvement, but we can at least start to see some of the shifting operations here and (sort) of what they're being applied to.

Second step: make some utility functions -

```
typedef unsigned long D3DCOLOR;

D3DCOLOR Alpha(D3DCOLOR color)
{
    return (color >> 24);
}

D3DCOLOR Red(D3DCOLOR color)
{
    return (color << 8) >> 24;
}

D3DCOLOR Green(D3DCOLOR color)
{
    return (color << 16) >> 24;
};

D3DCOLOR Blue(D3DCOLOR color)
{
    return (color << 24) >> 24;
}
```

Effectively, what's being done here is masking out each part (A, R, G, B) one at a time. I'm assuming it's in this format: it doesn't really matter if it isn't, because it's doing the same thing to each byte in the long. The only thing that will change is the order, but we'll stick with these function names for now. Let's add this into the mix:

```
return (factor<0.0f)
?
from 
: 
((factor>1.0f)
?
to
:
(Alpha(from) > Alpha(to))
?
(Alpha(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)(Alpha(from) - Alpha(to)))
:
((Alpha(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Alpha(to)- Alpha(from))))))) << 24
|
(Red(from) > Red(to))
?
((Red(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)(Red(from) - Red(to))))
:
(Red(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Red(to) - Red(from)))))) << 16
|
(Green(from) > Green(to))
?
((Green(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(Green(from) - Green(to)))
:
(Green(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Green(to) - Green(from)))))) << 8
|
(Blue(from) > Blue(to))
?
((Blue(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)(Blue(from) - Blue(to)))
:
(Blue(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Blue(to) - (Blue(from)))))) >> 24;
```

Ok, getting there. It's almost readable now. Note the parens here are something of a pain, and we must be careful to get them correct.

We can now do the (laborious) task of replacing ternary operators with `if/else`:

```
D3DCOLOR GetFadedColor(D3DCOLOR from, D3DCOLOR to, float factor)
{
    D3DCOLOR col = 0;

    if (factor < 0.0f) {
        col = from; 
    }
    else if (factor > 1.0f) {
        col = to;
    }
    else {
        if(Alpha(from) > Alpha(to)) {
            col = (Alpha(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Alpha(from) - Alpha(to))))) << 24;
        } 
        else {
            col = (Alpha(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Alpha(to)- Alpha(from))))) << 24;
        }

        if(Red(from) > Red(to)) {
            col |= (Red(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Red(from) - Red(to))))) << 16;
        }
        else {
            col |= (Red(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Red(to) - Red(from))))) << 16;
        }

        if(Green(from) > Green(to)) {
            col |= (Green(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Green(from) - Green(to))))) << 8;
        } 
        else {
            col |= (Green(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Green(to) - Green(from))))) << 8;
        }

        if(Blue(from) > Blue(to)) {
            col |= (Blue(from) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Blue(from) - Blue(to)))));
        }
        else {
            col |= (Blue(from) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor * (float)((Blue(to) - (Blue(from))))));
        }
    }

    return col;
}
```

Ok, so now it's readable. This can likely be simplified further - there's quite a bit of duplication here. All that really changes are some shift values. Hopefully this is enough that you can do that simplification yourself, however.

Comment: Not the worst abuse you've seen?  Wow.  This still makes me think twice about using it in my own programs.

Comment: @JamalA When I say it's not the worst, it's mainly the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/) that I'm thinking of. That being said, I'd never, ever let something like this get past any kind of code review.

Comment: Interesting link.  It seems to me that abusing the operator "doesn't count" there since it's a goal.  As for actual code review, like you said, this is a no-no.  I'm sort of obsessed with simple code, so I can't comprehend anything like this.

Comment: The conditionals (`if (Alpha(from) > Alpha(to))`) can also be omitted. In `a - f * (a - b)`, where a is greater than b, `a - b` is +ve; and where a is less than b, `a - b` is negative.

Comment: It could be much more improved for readability. Names are awfully incomprehensible. In such cases, using `x(y) {\n}` is not a good idea..

Answer (score 2):

@Yuushi has a really good answer here, but I am going to point out some slightly different things that I would do to make this better code

1. Whitespace between operators
2. Newline characters

```
return (factor < 0.0f) ? from 
    : ((factor > 1.0f) ? to 
    : (((((from >> 24) > (to >> 24)) ? ((from >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((from >> 24)-(to >> 24)))) 
    : ((from >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((to >> 24)-(from >> 24))))) << 24) 
        | (((((from << 8) >> 24) > ((to << 8) >> 24)) ? (((from << 8) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 8) >> 24) - ((to << 8) >> 24)))) 
    : (((from << 8) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 8) >> 24) - ((from << 8) >> 24))))) << 16) 
        | (((((from << 16) >> 24) > ((to << 16) >> 24)) ? (((from << 16) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 16) >> 24) - ((to << 16) >> 24)))) 
    : (((from << 16) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 16) >> 24) - ((from << 16) >> 24))))) <<8) | 
        (((((from << 24) >> 24) > ((to << 24) >> 24)) ? (((from << 24) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 24) >> 24) - ((to << 24) >> 24))))
    : (((from << 24) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 24) >> 24) - ((from << 24) >> 24))))))));
```

we can still go a little farther

```
return (factor < 0.0f) ? from 
    : ((factor > 1.0f) ? to 
    : (((((from >> 24) > (to >> 24)) ? 
        ((from >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((from >> 24) - (to >> 24)))) 
    : ((from >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)((to >> 24) - (from >> 24))))) << 24) 
        | (((((from << 8) >> 24) > ((to << 8) >> 24)) ?
        (((from << 8) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 8) >> 24) - ((to << 8) >> 24)))) 
    : (((from << 8) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 8) >> 24) - ((from << 8) >> 24))))) << 16) 
        | (((((from << 16) >> 24) > ((to << 16) >> 24)) ? 
        (((from << 16) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 16) >> 24) - ((to << 16) >> 24)))) 
    : (((from << 16) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 16) >> 24) - ((from << 16) >> 24))))) <<8) 
        | (((((from << 24) >> 24) > ((to << 24) >> 24)) ? 
        (((from << 24) >> 24) - (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((from << 24) >> 24) - ((to << 24) >> 24))))
    : (((from << 24) >> 24) + (D3DCOLOR)(factor*(float)(((to << 24) >> 24) - ((from << 24) >> 24))))))));
```

all I did was add Newline Characters and indentation to make your code more readable.

Another thing that I would suggest is to create variables for these numbers

- 8
- 16
- 24

and

Change the name of your `from` and `to` variables, I am guessing that they could be more descriptive.

and I am sure that you could clean this up a little bit more if you used the utility functions that @Yuushi talks about as well